# Entity Framework context.SaveChanges() slow - SQL Profiler included

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

I know EF isn't great for batch operations, but I am trying to understand an issue that we are having.

We are looping a text file, for which there are 5,000 products to be inserted in to our DB.

On calling context.SaveChanges() and watching the profiler I see:

Audit Login 0MS

RPC: Completed (the actual query to insert the product) Showing as 9 reads and a duration of 0 MS

Audit Logout **2750MS**

Why is the audit log out taking 2+ seconds? The actual SQL query is not taking any time at all, neither is the audit login.

Is this the overhead of EF? Has anyone got any suggestions? The only thing I have stumbled upon is pre generated views, but not sure if that will help or not.

Comment: So does it mean that it executes 5000 inserts within 2,75s?

Answer (score 0):

The logout itself isn't taking 2 seconds, profiler shows the duration of the session on the logout event, so it was 2750ms from login to logout.

Is there something happening in the application before it calls the logout that could take some time?  What happens between the time of the inserts and logout?

Comment: I figured it wasn't actually SQL server, I should have phrased my question better. How do I debug entity framework to find out what is causing the delay?

I have fixed this by just using Linq To Sql - got a batch import taking 4 hours down to 56 seconds using 'dated' orm :)